# Python 2.7 PyHamcrest 1.8.5 Matchers with unicode symbols

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, hamcrest

I was trying to get str for standard PyHamcrest matcher for loggin purposes:

```
from hamcrest import equal_to

print str(equal_to('string'))
print unicode(equal_to(u'❤'))
```

Second print fails because matcher has a "str" call inside.
I solved it with this class:

```
class UnicodeIsEqual(IsEqual):
    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(StringDescription().append_description_of(self))

print unicode(UnicodeIsEqual(u'❤'))
```

Is there a better way to do it without creating custom matcher?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using wrapper class, when needed:

```
class UnicodeMatcherWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, matcher):
        if hasattr(matcher, 'matcher'):
            matcher.matcher = UnicodeMatcherWrapper(matcher.matcher)

            if hasattr(matcher, 'matchers'):
                matcher.matchers = [UnicodeMatcherWrapper(nested_matcher) for nested_matcher in matcher.matchers]

        self.matcher = matcher

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return getattr(self.matcher, item)

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(StringDescription().append_description_of(self.matcher))
```